# 2DOF robot arm dynamic model (Double Compound Pendulum - Modeling without Lagrangian)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

Consider 2DOF robotic arm. No gravity. Instead of modeling it with two torque inputs at joints, I want to model it as two forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ applied at distance r (motor radius) from joints. Because, I think force is realistic, but torque is like a mathematical abstraction. I take two linear equations and one rotational equation about the center of mass for each rod.

Do you think this way of modeling is correct?

If yes, is there any difference between this model and the model which uses torque inputs (if $F_1r_1=\tau_1,F_2r_2=\tau_2$)? I ask because I was expecting at the end to get terms like $F_1r_1, F_2r_2$ (i.e. no r dependence, $F\cdot r$ product is important) but get r dependence.

[image]

Comment: Do you think this way of modeling is correct? The joint constraint forces are still unknown in your equations. To apply EL obtain  the kinetic energy as a function of the generalized coordinates . The potential energy is $~U=-\tau_1\alpha-\tau_2\beta$

Comment: Thank you for the comment. We can eliminate F3, F4, F5, F6 and get 2 equations in alpha, beta, F1 and F2. My aim is not to get equations but understand how it works. With Lagrangian I don't understand anything. Besides this, if we want to verify that equations we got are correct how would we do it? I want to apply the most straightforward way with free body diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem and a solution.

**The problem is:**

We cannot model torque produced by the motor as a single force vector at distance r. It is rather distributed over the circumference of stator (or rotor).

So we can model $\tau$ produced by motor more realistically as $F= \tau /r$ distributed as force density over the circumference. With this model, obviously, for each force density component there is another one with the same magnitude and opposite direction. So they cancel each other and net linear effect of this force distribution is zero. To find net torque produced by this force distribution about the center of mass of the rod we need to integrate $\tau_{net}=\int_0^{2\pi}\vec{p}\times\vec{F}_d \cdot rd\theta$. (Here $F_d=F/2\pi r$ is force density). While computing we get this torque to be exactly equal to torque produced by motor about the joint (independent of r and R).

[image]
This simplifes the modeling and now we can write equations as:

[image]
Here we can eliminate $F_3, F_4, F_5, F_6$ and get two equations in $\alpha, \beta, \tau_1$ and $\tau_2$. This concludes the modeling. We have a non-linear dynamical system with two inputs and two outputs. By the way, adding effect of gravity to these equations is easy, you just add $-m_1g, -m_2g$ to equations 2 and 5 respectively.